# The third conditional use of "could"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

The whole context:

> So I decided to make some meat pies. In a short time I was busy mixing butter and flour and my hands were soon covered with sticky pastry. At exactly that moment, the telephone rang. **Nothing *could have been* more annoying**.

According to the concept of the third conditional tense, "*Nothing could have been more annoying*" should be an unreal situation, but what is the real situation in this case?? I can't figure out the logic in it.

Comment: It is not a third conditional. It's the past tense: Nothing can be more annoying than getting a phone call when you are in the shower. Past tense: could have been. They could be great [future idea]; They could have been great [past idea].

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your answer. Since the construction is the same when implies past action or unreal situation in the past, how could I tell which is which?

Answer (score 1):

The "unreal" situation is that "Nothing" did not happen. Instead, something happened: The telephone rang.

Compare:

> A knock at the door could have been more irritating.

Here the "unreal" situation is the door knock (which didn't occur)

I don't think this analysis is very useful.  Instead treat this as an idiom: "Nothing could have been more ..." to mean "It was the most ... thing."